# How to animate ag-grid container with ng-include?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I am using a `ng-include` to dynamically load template in my Angular application. One of my template has ag-grid.I am using a simple fade in fade out angular animation all the other templates animates with `ng-iclude`, other than the template which has ag-grid. The following is the simplified problem I am having.

the animation will work if removed `ag-grid` directive (`<div ag-grid="gridOptions" class="ag-fresh" ></div>`) in template script.

How solve this problem?

```js
agGrid.initialiseAgGridWithAngular1(angular);

var module = angular.module("example", ["agGrid", "ngAnimate"]);

module.controller("exampleCtrl", function($scope) {

  var columnDefs = [{headerName: "Make",field: "make"},
    {headerName: "Model",field: "model"},
    {headerName: "Price",field: "price"}
  ];

  var rowData = [{make: "Toyota", model: "Celica",price: 35000},
    {make: "Ford",model: "Mondeo",price: 32000},
    {make: "Porsche",model: "Boxter",price: 72000}
  ];

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: rowData
  };

  $scope.url = null;

  $scope.setDlg = function() {

    if (!$scope.url)
      $scope.url = 'test.html';
    else
      $scope.url = null;
  }

});
```

```css
#wrap {
  width: 452px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: red;
  padding: 25px;
}

.ag-fresh{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.animateStartUpScreen.ng-enter,
.animateStartUpScreen.ng-enter .model {
  transition: all 5000ms;
  /*transition-delay: 1000ms;*/
}

.animateStartUpScreen.ng-enter .model {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}

.animateStartUpScreen.ng-enter.ng-enter-active .model {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ag-grid/6.3.0/ag-grid.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="example" ng-controller="exampleCtrl">

  <button type="" ng-click="setDlg()">show dialog</button>

  <div ng-include="url" class="animateStartUpScreen" style="overflow: hidden;"></div>


  <script type="text/ng-template" id="test.html">

    <div id="wrap" class="model">
      <div ag-grid="gridOptions" class="ag-fresh" ></div>
    </div>

  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: can you not use `angular-ui` or something similar for showing modal instead? (comes with animation out of the box I guess)

Comment: @tanmay I had used my custom dialog showing mechanism in my application its difficult change and test from the begining.